# AutoCompleteTextView suggestion box show behind keyboard when inside BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The suggestion box from AutoCompleteTextView beehives differently based on the method used to display it.
Ideally both should display the box above the keyboard, any suggestions how to fix it?

**[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InXNutqQM6Y)**

**[GitHub](https://github.com/rubenslopes/AutoCompleteTextView-with-CustomAdapter)**

**SearchMusic.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:background="#fffbbb"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="Music name or artist" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using AutoCompleteTextView = Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView;
using Button = Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatButton;

namespace AutoComplete
{
    [Activity(Label = "AutoComplete", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("songs.json")))
            {
                var autoComplete = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoComplete);
                var songs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<Song>>(reader.ReadToEnd());

                autoComplete.Adapter = new SongAdapter(songs);
            }

            var bottomSheet = FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottomSheet);
            var buttonEmbed = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonEmbed);
            var buttonFragment = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonFragment);

            var bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.From(bottomSheet);

            buttonEmbed.Click += delegate
            {
                bottomSheetBehavior.State = BottomSheetBehavior.StateExpanded;
            };

            buttonFragment.Click += delegate
            {
                var searchMusicFragment = new SearchMusicFragment();
                searchMusicFragment.Show(SupportFragmentManager, searchMusicFragment.Tag);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchMusicFragment**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using AutoCompleteTextView = Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView;

namespace AutoComplete
{
    public class SearchMusicFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment
    {
        public override void SetupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style)
        {
            base.SetupDialog(dialog, style);
            var view = View.Inflate(Activity, Resource.Layout.SearchMusic, null);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("songs.json")))
            {
                var autoComplete = view.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoComplete);
                var songs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<Song>>(reader.ReadToEnd());

                autoComplete.Adapter = new SongAdapter(songs);
            }

            dialog.SetContentView(view);

            //var layout = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)((View)view.Parent).LayoutParameters;
            //var behavior = layout.Behavior;

            //if (behavior != null)
            //    ((BottomSheetBehavior)behavior).SetBottomSheetCallback();
        }
    }
}
```